# Why is NgRx store being initialized every time a page under the Angular lazy loaded module is reached?

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, ngrx

Hello I have a lazy loaded module (shoeSalesModule). ngrx/store/init appears to be called every time I load a component/navigate to a child page. Also, loadChildren is invoked each time a new page is reached. As a result the store is reset. Is there a way to preserve the store's state and only call init once? Here is my code. I am using Angular 12. Thanks!

EDIT: Tried moving `forRoot` to app.module but I still see the same behavior where the store is reinitialized:

app.module.ts

```
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http'
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core'
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser'
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations'
import { StoreModule } from '@ngrx/store'
import { StoreDevtoolsModule } from '@ngrx/store-devtools'

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module'
import { AppComponent } from './app.component'
import { HttpService } from './shared/http.service'

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    StoreModule.forRoot({}),
    StoreDevtoolsModule.instrument({
      maxAge: 25, // Retains this number of states
      // logOnly: environment.production, // Restrict extension to log-only mode
    }),
  ],
  providers: [
    HttpService
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

shoeSalesModule.ts:

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        //components declared here
    ],
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        shoeSalesAppStoreModule,
        shoeSalesRoutingModule,
        MatButtonModule,
        MatFormFieldModule,
        MatInputModule,
        MatIconModule,
        FormsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        MatDatepickerModule,
        MatNativeDateModule,
 StoreModule.forFeature(
            'shoeSalesFeatureKey', shoeSalesReducer
        ),
        EffectsModule.forRoot([shoeSalesEffects]),
    ],
    exports: [
        //components here
    ]
})
export class shoeSalesModule { }
```

app-routing.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'shoeSales',
    loadChildren: () => { console.log("loading children"); return import('./shoeSales/shoeSales.module').then(m => m.ShoeSalesModule) }
  },
 
]

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

shoeSalesRoutingModule.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        pathMatch: 'full',
        redirectTo: '/shoesSales/buy'
    },
    {
        path: 'buy',
        component: BuyComponent
    },
    {
        path: 'finalize-purchase',
        component: FinalizePurchaseComponent
    }
]

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class shoeSalesRoutingModule { }
```

EDIT 2:
It seems that AppComponent's constructor is being called every time I navigate to a new page

Comment: Your main module (app.module I guess in most cases) ahould be the one with the store forRoot. Lazy loaded modules should be using forFeature and add their state slices to the forRoot store. Does that make sense?

Comment: [MikeOne](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2295103/mikeone) Thanks for your suggestion. I tried it but I still see the same behavior

Comment: I also tried moving forRoot and forFeature into app.module just to see what would happen but that yielded the same result

Comment: The problem seems to occur when I enter the route manually but not when I use ```router.navigate```